# Dependency Inversion and interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

Im learning OOP, specifically interfaces. I'm also trying to learn SOLID, in this case the D.

From [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-4-the-dependency-inversion-principle--net-36872) site, the initial program implements a 'concretion' - in this case `PDFBook` is typehinted to be passed to the constructor. Later, 
this typehint is changed to a general `EBook` interface. Anything that implements this interface is accepted. Makes sense in this case.

However, even when coding to an interface, I find that there are often extra methods not defined in the interface, but are unique to that concretion.
In this case, PDFBook may have a method `doDPFOnlyThing` not defined in any of the other classes that implement the `EBook` interface.

If I pass a `PDFBook` object to `myFunc()` which type-hints the `EBook` interface, from what I understand, if I use *only* the methods defined in the interface - `read()` - then this would adhere to DIP yes? As in, anything passed into `myFunc()` implementing the interface will be able to have their `read()` method called as it adheres to the interface contract.

```
myFunc(Ebook $book) {

    $book->read();
}
```

What if `myFunc()` has to use `doDPFOnlyThing()` available only in the PDFBook class? I assume this would add dependencies since this method only exists in the `PDFBook` concretion?

```
myFunc(Ebook $book) {

    $book->doDPFOnlyThing();
}
```

What is the better thing to do in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whereas typehinting to interfaces over implementations is helpful in reducing coupling, it can also be a pain when trying to write generalized interfaces.  As you said, it would be nice to use methods you *know* are there.

That said, you effectively have two different methods there.  When calling `myFunc` and passing an `EBook` you should definitely only *rely* on methods in the interface.  If a method needs to call `doPDFOnlyThing` and it relies on an `EBook` instead of a `PDFBook`, well that will violate the principle.

One thing you could do is:

```
public myFunc(EBook $book)
{
    $book->read();
}

public myPDFFunc(PDFBook $book)
{
    $book->read(); //Still valid from EBook contract
    $book->doPDFOnlyThing();
}
```

Although this will probably work, it is a dirty fix you will likely end up violating Open/Closed principle in the process since you will be coming back and editing the class.  (Eventually the customer will want a `KindleBook` which has a `doKindleOnlyThing` method in it.)

**So how does one get around this problem?**

You problem of wanting to type-hint to one interface but using methods from an implementation is like having your cake and eating it too...

To solve this you will need to abstract your design more.  Let's use the example that you are making a client that will read books in various formats all derived from the `EBook` interface implemented as the base class `MyEBook`.  Let's start with the code below:

```
interface EBook
{
    public function read();
}

interface PDFBook extends EBook
{
    public function doPDFOnlyThing();
}

class MyEBook implements EBook
{
    public function read()
    {
        echo 'reading from a ' . get_class($this);
    }
}

class MyPDFBook extends MyEBook implements PDFBook
{
    public function read()
    {
        //you only need to override this method
        //if needed, otherwise you can leave it
        //out and default to the parent class
        //implementation.
        parent::read();
    }

    public function doPDFOnlyThing()
    {
        echo 'doing what a PDF does while...';
    }
}
```

The `EBook` interface contracts the `read()` method and the `PDFBook` interface extends `EBook` and adds the `doPDFOnlyThing()` method to the contract.  The concrete implementations `MyEBook` and `MyPDFBook` will each use their respective interfaces.

Next we need to build some *handler* classes that can take any book and perform an action of some kind on them.  We will use a naming convention here where all handler classes have the suffix of `Reader` behind them.  So the handler for `MyPDFBook` would be `MyPDFBookReader`. This convention will be handy a little later.

We will start with an abstract class that can accept any implementation of `EBook` and store it in a class property.  The class will also expect that all children classes implement a method called `readBook()`.

```
abstract class GenericBookReader
{
    protected $book;

    public function __construct(EBook $book)
    {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    abstract public function readBook();
}
```

Now that we have the abstract class that can accept any `EBook` we can build the specific implementations that will type-hint to the particular interface class - e.g. `PDFBook` or `EBook`.

```
class MyBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(EBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        $this->book->read();
    }
}

class MyPDFBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(PDFBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        //You are safe to use PDFBook methods here
        //because you have a guarantee they are available
        $this->book->doPDFOnlyThing();
        $this->book->read();
    }
}
```

Both of these concrete implementations simply send the given object in `$book` to the parent constructor which will then cache it in the `$this->book` property.  Any operations that need to be done to any book when being initialized can be done in `GenericBookReader` and all classes will use the new method instead of having to be individually updated.  Of course if a particular class needs some special initialization that can be done in their own constructors instead of the parent constructor.

At this point you have abstracted the `EBook` and `PDFBook` away from each other in their own handlers instead of in a single class.  This is a step forward because now in the `readBook()` method of the `MyPDFBookReader` class you have a guarantee that `doPDFOnlyThing()` is available for use.

Now to glue all of this together you need a client that reads books.  The client should be able to accept any `EBook`, determine the type of book it is, create the appropriate `Reader` class and then call the `readBook()` method.  The naming convention works nice here since we can build class names dynamically.

```
class BookClient
{
    public function readBook(EBook $book)
    {
        //Get the class name of $book
        $name = get_class($book);

        //Make the 'reader' class name and see if it exists
        $readerClass = $name . 'Reader';
        if (class_exists($readerClass))
        {
            //Class exists - yay!  Read the book...
            $reader = new $readerClass($book);
            $reader->readBook();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the usage of these classes:

```
$client = new BookClient();
$client->readBook(new MyEBook());       //prints: reading from a MyBook
$client->readBook(new MyPDFBook());     //prints: doing what a PDF does while...reading from a MyPDFBook
```

All of this might look complex just to do a simple call to `readBook()` but the flexibility gained is worth it.  For example, later on the customer says *"Where's the support for Kindle books?"*  and you say *"Coming right up!"*

```
interface KindleBook extends EBook
{
    public function doKindleOnlyThing();
}

class MyKindleBook extends MyEBook implements KindleBook
{
    public function doKindleOnlyThing()
    {
        echo 'waiting FOREVER for the stupid menu to start...';
    }
}

class MyKindleBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(KindleBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        //You are safe to use KindleBook methods here
        //because you have a guarantee they are available
        $this->book->doKindleOnlyThing();
        $this->book->read();
    }
}
```

Example usage extended:

```
$client = new BookClient();
$client->readBook(new MyEBook());       //prints: reading from a MyBook
$client->readBook(new MyPDFBook());     //prints: doing what a PDF does while...reading from a MyPDFBook
$client->readBook(new MyKindleBook());  //prints: waiting FOREVER for the stupid menu to start...reading from a MyKindleBook
```

This particular setup using abstraction stands up well to Open/Closed principle.  You had to *add* some code, but you *didn't change any of the existing implementation* - not even the client!

Hopefully this provided an extra angle to view your issue from.  Look at the way you want to setup your implementations and start looking at what can be abstracted away. Sometimes it is best to keep objects in the dark about each other and have special handlers that work with them.  In this example none of the books need to care how the other one work.  Therefore a single class that would accept any `EBook` but has methods that work with specific children implementations of that interface ends up being a code smell.

Hope that helps.  Below is the complete example code to copy and paste to try out yourself.

```
<?php

interface EBook
{
    public function read();
}

interface PDFBook extends EBook
{
    public function doPDFOnlyThing();
}

interface KindleBook extends EBook
{
    public function doKindleOnlyThing();
}

class MyEBook implements EBook
{
    public function read()
    {
        echo 'reading from a ' . get_class($this);
    }
}

class MyPDFBook extends MyEBook implements PDFBook
{
    public function read()
    {
        //you only need to override this method
        //if needed, otherwise you can leave it
        //out and default to the parent class
        //implementation.
        parent::read();
    }

    public function doPDFOnlyThing()
    {
        echo 'doing what a PDF does while...';
    }
}

class MyKindleBook extends MyEBook implements KindleBook
{
    public function doKindleOnlyThing()
    {
        echo 'waiting FOREVER for the stupid menu to start...';
    }
}

abstract class GenericBookReader
{
    protected $book;

    public function __construct(EBook $book)
    {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    abstract public function readBook();
}

class MyBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(EBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        $this->book->read();
    }
}

class MyPDFBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(PDFBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        //You are safe to use PDFBook methods here
        //because you have a guarantee they are available
        $this->book->doPDFOnlyThing();
        $this->book->read();
    }
}

class MyKindleBookReader extends GenericBookReader
{
    public function __construct(KindleBook $book)
    {
        parent::__construct($book);
    }

    public function readBook()
    {
        //You are safe to use KindleBook methods here
        //because you have a guarantee they are available
        $this->book->doKindleOnlyThing();
        $this->book->read();
    }
}

class BookClient
{
    public function readBook(EBook $book)
    {
        //Get the class name of $book
        $name = get_class($book);

        //Make the 'reader' class name and see if it exists
        $readerClass = $name . 'Reader';
        if (class_exists($readerClass))
        {
            //Class exists - yay!  Read the book...
            $reader = new $readerClass($book);
            $reader->readBook();
        }
    }
}
$client = new BookClient();
$client->readBook(new MyEBook());       //prints: reading from a MyBook
$client->readBook(new MyPDFBook());     //prints: doing what a PDF does while...reading from a MyPDFBook
$client->readBook(new MyKindleBook());  //prints: waiting FOREVER for the stupid menu to start...reading from a MyKindleBook
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer deserving of a bounty (tomorrow). You have given a better detailed explanation than some retail books I have purchased.

Comment: @myol Also, if it is worth it to you at all, a while back I came across [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28704514/2635601) that I wrote a (winded) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28775868/2635601) to that also talked about some OOP principles, design, abstraction, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that link is also very helpful. One question though, why do you use an abstract class for `GenericBookReader`? What is the advantage to that?

Comment: @myol I used the abstract class because I can provide some base functionality while also contracting methods the children classes must implement - something interfaces can't do.  If I didn't do that I would have to create a property `$book` in every `Reader` class and assign it during the constructor of every class.  There also wouldn't be the possibility of having default behavior. If you needed to set the author's name of a book the method `setAuthor($author)` fits well in the parent class instead of repeating yourself over all classes.  Only 3 classes in the example, but what if it was 20?

Comment: I looked up some material on abstract classes and now I think I understand. It's like a partially built class that can have its normal methods inherited but has the interface contract feature of interfaces? Something between a regular class and a pure interface?

Comment: Yep. That is a good way of looking at them.  Abstract classes can't be instantiated either so the must be implemented with a concrete class just like interfaces.  Abstract classes can also be a way to implement an interface and provide default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is a heavily discussed one, but one option is to create an interface which adheres to the *entire* definition of the object that you implement.

However, this violates the [Open/Closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle, since perhaps all of the methods in your implementation are not actually required as a dependency where you need it.  Read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446502/dependency-injection-using-interfaces) for more details.

The other option is to create an interface for the *exact* dependencies that you need in your classes, then chose an implementation that implements only those dependencies.  Sometimes you may need to create a new implementation, [refactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) an existing implementation, or [create a wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) around existing implementations

Comment: Thanks, I decided to create an interface for the exact dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In this case It also violates the "L" of SOLID , as a reference has a chance of throwing `NOSuchMethodFoundException`  as in Java.

In your case, you need two interfaces, one having only the `read()` function and the other having `doPDFOnlyThing()` so now you have created an adapter with which the lower level concretion can be called, later you can also use this Interace containing `doPDFOnlyThing()` for other concretions like Image Pdf, secured Pdf etc. Thus you need to realize two interface.